# Order a parent/child list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I have a problem to sort a list based on parent child.

Here is code available on [C# dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QHkbTA#&togetherjs=TREMRl2yu1)

This is the model of Section Object:

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //dont care
    public int SectionID { get; set; } //the actual ID I use
    public int SectionRowId { get; set; } //something else
    public string Name { get; set; } //just display
    public int ParentID { get; set; } //parent id connection
}
```

There is a list of sections that can be in any kind of mixed order.

```
 Random R = new Random().Next(1000);

 new Section() { Id = 9,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 900,     SectionRowId = 1, ParentID = 3     }   
,new Section() { Id = 5,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 137,     SectionRowId = 4, ParentID = 0     }   
,new Section() { Id = 8,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 3,       SectionRowId = 3, ParentID = 137   } 
,new Section() { Id = 1,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 888,     SectionRowId = 1, ParentID = 0     }   
,new Section() { Id = 3,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 137,     SectionRowId = 2, ParentID = 0     }   
,new Section() { Id = 4,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 137,     SectionRowId = 3, ParentID = 888   } 
,new Section() { Id = 6,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 3,       SectionRowId = 1, ParentID = 0     }   
,new Section() { Id = 7,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 3,       SectionRowId = 2, ParentID = 0     }   
,new Section() { Id = 2,    Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 137,     SectionRowId = 1, ParentID = 0     }   
,new Section() { Id = 10,   Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 11,      SectionRowId = 1, ParentID = 900   } 
,new Section() { Id = 11,   Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 8,       SectionRowId = 1, ParentID = 137   } 
,new Section() { Id = 12,   Name = R.Next(1000).ToString(), SectionID = 8,       SectionRowId = 2, ParentID = 0     }
```

The expected result:

```
    Id    SectionId / SectionRowId (Parent SectionID)
    01) - [ 888 / 001 ]
    02) - [ 137 / 001 ]
    03) - [ 137 / 002 ]
    04) - [ 137 / 003 ] <- 888      // is available before ^^
    05) - [ 137 / 004 ]
    06) - [ 003 / 001 ]
    07) - [ 003 / 002 ]
    08) - [ 003 / 003 ] <- 137      // is available before ^^
    09) - [ 900 / 001 ] <- 003      // is available before ^^
    10) - [ 011 / 001 ] <- 900      // is available before ^^
    11) - [ 008 / 001 ] <- 137      // is available before ^^
    12) - [ 008 / 002 ]
```

The legend for above expected result:

```
Example 04) - [ 137 / 003 ] <- 888      // is available before ^^
```

*888 is the parent of 137 and it is available before this one.*

```
01) - [ 888 / 001 ]
```

*If it was bellow this one then it wouldn't be good.*

**EDIT:**

Please take a look to: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FCZF5X#&togetherjs=aIbJ64NwJv
I have added it to be all random and a checker for it. So it could be more understandable.

From the new random code this is how it should look like:

```
Items count: 12
Final result is: True


            [ ORIGINAL LIST ]               |                [ SORTED LIST ]                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ID    |    Section / Row     |   Parent   |     ID    |    Section / Row     |   Parent      

025116) - [ 004337 / 084754 ] <-- 011973    |    008134) - [ 011973 / 018572 ]
028628) - [ 006663 / 045806 ] <-- 011973    |    083009) - [ 011973 / 013626 ]
099494) - [ 004337 / 075769 ] <-- 006663    |    080161) - [ 011973 / 023149 ]
051824) - [ 004337 / 086590 ]               |    059540) - [ 011973 / 045751 ]
008134) - [ 011973 / 045751 ]               |    078203) - [ 011973 / 061979 ]
002017) - [ 005938 / 073913 ] <-- 011973    |    025800) - [ 006663 / 045806 ]
083009) - [ 011973 / 023149 ]               |    028628) - [ 006663 / 082944 ] <-- 011973
037537) - [ 005938 / 038984 ] <-- 004337    |    051824) - [ 004337 / 075769 ]
025800) - [ 006663 / 082944 ]               |    099494) - [ 004337 / 084754 ] <-- 006663
080161) - [ 011973 / 018572 ]               |    025116) - [ 004337 / 086590 ] <-- 011973
059540) - [ 011973 / 061979 ]               |    037537) - [ 005938 / 038984 ] <-- 004337
078203) - [ 011973 / 013626 ]               |    002017) - [ 005938 / 073913 ] <-- 011973
```

Summary of sorted list above ^^:

- ID       = not important
- Section  = must be grouped together
- Row      = Must be ordered ascending
- Parent   = **If have, the parent section group must be above this group.**

Comment: Can you add column names to your expected result?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I haven't downvoted, but the question is not clear and given fiddle contains too much unnecessary detail.

Comment: @ilkerkaran yes sorry I will edit now

Comment: @TreeGround It looks like you just want to order by id, you can use `.OrderBy( x => x.Id)` I think

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I though would be better to post something live instead of trying to explain in written because it is not so simple to explain it.

Comment: @EpicKip if it would be that easy :) haha, no lets say the ID field can be a random number. I just put it there in order so it could explain better.

Comment: @TreeGround Ok, but I honestly don't understand these `<- 137      // is available before ^^`. What are your exact requirements for ordering?

Comment: @EpicKip I edited maybe better now? :/

Comment: @TreeGround Yes, the cut up part where you explain the line helps! Ill see what I can do

Comment: This could still be a lot better explained. Apparently `ParentID` is a reference to a `SectionID`? Apparently inside each Section (?) should be in `SectionRowId` order  and apparently the answer doesn't need an `Id` column? So the result is sort rows in section by `SectionRowId` and  sort Sections by `ParentId` of any row above the Section. It may be more helpful if you had put some C# classes in your question.

Comment: Is there any particular reason section `008` is after section `003` and not before it?

Comment: @NetMage yes something like you explained, what kind of classes should I put in question? And for 008 being after 003 I dont understand where? In initialization of list? no particular reason it can be random, I am making now a random initializer of list.

Comment: @NetMage Do you know to solve it?

Comment: I can solve it for one parent per group in a LINQ query, multiple parents per group is going to require more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it for now... if anyone else would need in future.

```
private static List<Section> SortTheList(List<Section> messyList)
    {
        List<Section> newList = new List<Section>();
        List<Section> outList = new List<Section>();
        newList.AddRange(messyList);

        int[] sectionIDs = newList.Select(x => x.SectionID).Distinct().ToArray();
        int[] no = GetOrder(newList).ToArray();
        foreach (int sectionID in no)
        {
            IEnumerable<Section> thisSectionGroup = newList.Where(x => x.SectionID == sectionID);
            thisSectionGroup = thisSectionGroup.OrderBy(x => x.SectionRowId).ThenBy(x => x.ParentID);
            outList.AddRange(thisSectionGroup);
        }

        return outList;
    }

    private static List<int> GetOrder(List<Section> allSections)
    {

        Dictionary<int, int> orderList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int[] sectionIDs = allSections.Select(x => x.SectionID).Distinct().ToArray();
        foreach (int sectionID in sectionIDs) { orderList.Add(sectionID, 0); }
        foreach (int sectionID in sectionIDs)
        {
            int[] parentIDs = allSections.Where(x => x.SectionID == sectionID && x.ParentID > 0).Select(x => x.ParentID).ToArray();
            foreach (int parentID in parentIDs)
            {
                IncParents(allSections, parentID, ref orderList);
            }
        }
        return orderList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
    }

    private static void IncParents(List<Section> allSections, int parentID, ref Dictionary<int, int> orderList, int incLevel = 1)
    {
        orderList[parentID] = orderList[parentID] + incLevel;
        int[] parentIDs = allSections.Where(x => x.SectionID == parentID && x.ParentID > 0).Select(x => x.ParentID).ToArray();
        foreach (int subParentID in parentIDs)
        {
            IncParents(allSections, subParentID, ref orderList, (incLevel + 1));
        }
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1VNqSB

Feel free to improve it or make it more elegant :)

Comment: Don't link to external sites unless the content is already in the answer.

Comment: Also, calling `new Random().Next(1000)` like that will give you repeated values. Always use a single instance of `Random` (per thread).

Comment: How does `Id`, `SectionID`, and `ParentID` relate to each other? If I knew that I could probably give you a three-liner.

Comment: @Enigmativity hi, sectionid and parentid are related, id is not important, rowid should be ordered asc.

Comment: **How are `SectionID` and `ParentID` related?** It's not like a normal parent/child relationship - there's two `137 on each side.

Comment: @Enigmativity :) SectionID can have multiple rows that's SectionRowID, the ParentID is related to [SectionID + SectionRowID]

Comment: That's not explaining how. I think I can give you a simple answer, but I need to understand the relationships. Saying that "ParentID is related to [SectionID + SectionRowID]" isn't enough - how are they related? Can you break it down further?

Comment: @Enigmativity I dont understand what is not clear? I will narrow the view on that list above. So lets say there is multiple items in a list. Those items have following properties (ID, Counter, ParentID) **All of those values can be random!** An item can be related to another item and specific Counter, when it is then its ParentID is the ID+Counter of the parent item.

Comment: `ID+Counter`? I can't see items in your sample data that have that property? If you said `X = Y + Z` and `X = 5, Y = 2, & Z = 3` then I can understand the relationship, but I'm not seeing it with your data.

Comment: I'm trying to help answer your question. You had it up for 4 days without an answer and then you had to answer it yourself. It's really not a very clear question.